# Splitting touchesMoved across a single SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touch-event

Using SpriteKit, I have created a SKSpriteNode called lightSaber, and using the touchesMoved method, I am able to either rotate the SKSpriteNode or translate it left or right. Is there a way to make it so it does one or the either depending on where I grab the SKSpriteNode? (e.g. the blade or the handle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the position of the touchEvent via

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
```

This will give you the capability to add custom logic to where you touch the screen. For example:

```
if(location.x > 300) {
   //Do this
} else {
   //Do that
}
```

You could also make the sword in two pieces, i.e two nodes and name each node and listen to a touch event on both nodes.

Get the node within `touchesBegan` by

```
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
if([node.name isEqualToString@"Handle"]) {

} else if ([node.name isEqualToString@"Blade"]) {

}
```

Comment: But the blade and handle are not always one on top of the other, since touching the blade would rotate the Lightsaber, so location.x > 300 wouldn't necessarily help. Separating it into two objects is also not very practical since they always need to be touching and oriented correctly.